# Best way to implement a "server" class in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, class, static

I'm doing an application for Android. One of my classes is Sound which offers methods like `playAlarm()` and `playSong(String name)`. Whats the best way to implement that kind of class, as an object accessed with a singleton or as a static class with those static methods? From the point of view of app perfomance in Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably little difference in performance but using a singleton instead of static methods will make it easier to unit test.

Barry